# How to make wxPython, DC background transparent?

Tags: c++, python, wxpython, wxwidgets

How can i make the default white DC background become invisible (transparent)?

Run the following example, it shows a white background over a button. I would like to remove the white background of the DC. (to show only the red X)

```
import wx


class drawover(wx.Window):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Window.__init__(self, parent)


        self.Bind(wx.EVT_PAINT, self.OnPaint)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_ERASE_BACKGROUND, self.OnErase)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_SET_FOCUS, self.OnFocus)


    def OnFocus(self, evt):
        self.GetParent().SetFocus()


    def OnErase(self, evt):
        pass


    def OnPaint(self, evt):
        dc = wx.PaintDC(self)
        dc.BeginDrawing()
        dc.SetPen(wx.Pen("RED", 1))
        dc.DrawLineList([(0,0,100,100), (100,0,0,100)])
        dc.EndDrawing()


class frame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, size=(600,600))


        s = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)


        self.tc1 = wx.TextCtrl(self, style=wx.TE_MULTILINE)
        s.Add(self.tc1, 1, wx.EXPAND)
        self.tc2 = wx.Button(self)
        s.Add(self.tc2, 1, wx.EXPAND)


        self.d = drawover(self.tc2)


        self.tc2.Bind(wx.EVT_SIZE, self.OnSize2)


        self.SetSizer(s)
        self.Layout()


    def OnSize2(self, evt):
        self.d.SetSize((101,101))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    a = wx.App(0)
    b = frame()
    b.Show(1)
    a.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 2):

http://wiki.wxpython.org/Transparent%20Frames

If you are on windows just see above.

If not you basically have to capture the frame below it as an image and paint it (in your onpaint) to fake it

also see
http://wxpython-users.1045709.n5.nabble.com/Transparent-Panels-td2303275.html